# Are move semantics implied immediately before an rvalue is destroyed?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following function:

```
void SetObject(Object object) 
{
    m_Object = object;
}
```

The `SetObject` would receive a copy of `object`, which is an rvalue that is assigned to `m_Object` and immediately goes out of scope.

Would move semantics be implied so that a second copy of `object` isn't created unnecessarily? Seems like move semantics should be implied, though I'm likely missing something. In other words, do I need to write this as follows?

```
void SetObject(Object object) 
{
    m_Object = std::move(object);
}
```

Comment: You need the `move()`. Even if the compiler *could* deduce the object is going out of scope later, it's not required to.

Comment: Notice that "assignment to a member" and "return statement" do not have the same rules in this instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object` parameter of `SetObject()` may or may not have been *initialized* from an rvalue at the call site, but inside of `SetObject()` it is certainly not an rvalue, it is an lvalue (as it has a name).

As such:

```cpp
void SetObject(Object object) 
{
    m_Object = object;
}
```

will perform a *copy* into `m_Object`, not a *move*.

You need to use `std::move()` explicitly to cast `object` into an rvalue in order to perform a *move* into `m_Object` (assuming `Object` supports move semantics, otherwise a *copy* will be performed):

```cpp
void SetObject(Object object) 
{
    m_Object = std::move(object);
}
```

Comment: Ah. Clearly I'm foggy on what constitutes an lvalue. So, anything with a name is an lvalue?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys yes. See [Value Categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need `std::move` to avoid the copy.